# Eclipse IDE - Unable to Save Resources EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE_REQUEST

Tags: error, eclipse, force.com-ide

I am new to Salesforce and I'm trying to save files to the Salesforce server. I have a lot of files to save but when I hit "Save to Server," I get this error message:

[image]

I tried looking onine for this issue but I can't seem to find someone who posted with a similar error. The similar errors were related to Data Loader and not to Eclipse.

Am I saving incorrectly? Or do I need to change something in eclipse.ini file?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What all do you have in your `package.xml`? Usually for development you should just have `ApexClass`, `ApexComponent`, `ApexPage`, `ApexTrigger`, and `StaticResource`. Maybe `CustomLabel`.

Comment: Can you try to save subset of files? this seems like governor limit on request size. If you split your request then it should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 50 MB limit to the size of a SOAP API payload, as well as a corresponding limit of 39 MB of payload when using the [metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm). You'll need to deploy just some of the files at once instead of all of them.

Comment: Thanks! I hit Cmd + s and miraculously the project saved! However, doing that right click and "Save to Server" doesn't work. Do you happen to know the difference between them?

Comment: @akcorp2003 depending on your project settings, auto-build might use the Tooling API rather than the metadata API. I suspect that may have happened here. It's entirely possible that you may have even triggered some obscure bug, or maybe even might have some other plugin messing with what gets deployed. You might try going over to github and posting an issue on the force.com ide project, so it can be formally investigated.